# luigi target for non-existent table

Tags: python, hadoop, hive, scheduler

I'm trying to set up a simple table existence test for a luigi task using `luigi.hive.HiveTableTarget`

I create a simple table in hive just to make sure it is there:

```
create table test_table (a int);
```

Next I set up the target with luigi:

```
from luigi.hive import HiveTableTarget
target = HiveTableTarget(table='test_table')

>>> target.exists()
True
```

Great, next I try it with a table I know ***doesn't*** exist to make sure it returns false.

```
target = HiveTableTarget(table='test_table_not_here')

>>> target.exists()
```

And it raises an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/luigi/hive.py", line 344, in exists
    return self.client.table_exists(self.table, self.database)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/luigi/hive.py", line 117, in table_exists
    stdout = run_hive_cmd('use {0}; describe {1}'.format(database, table))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/luigi/hive.py", line 62, in run_hive_cmd
    return run_hive(['-e', hivecmd], check_return_code)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/luigi/hive.py", line 56, in run_hive
    stdout, stderr)
luigi.hive.HiveCommandError: ('Hive command: hive -e use default; describe test_table_not_here
failed with error code: 17', '', '\nLogging initialized using configuration in
jar:file:/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.2.0-1.cdh5.2.0.p0.36/jars/hive-common-0.13.1-
cdh5.2.0.jar!/hive-log4j.properties\nOK\nTime taken: 0.822 seconds\nFAILED: 
SemanticException [Error 10001]: Table not found test_table_not_here\n')
```

*edited formatting for clarity*

I don't understand that last line of the exception. Of course the table is not found, that is the whole point of an existence check. Is this the expected behavior or do I have some configuration issue I need to work out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so it looks like this may have been a bug in the latest tagged release (1.0.19) but it is fixed on the master branch. The code responsible is the line:

```
stdout = run_hive_cmd('use {0}; describe {1}'.format(database, table))
return not "does not exist" in stdout
```

which is changed in the master to be:

```
stdout = run_hive_cmd('use {0}; show tables like "{1}";'.format(database, table))
return stdout and table in stdout
```

The latter works fine whereas the former throws a `HiveCommandError`.

If you want a solution without having to update to the master branch, you could create your own target class with minimal effort:

```
from luigi.hive import HiveTableTarget, run_hive_cmd

class MyHiveTarget(HiveTableTarget):
    def exists(self):
        stdout = run_hive_cmd('use {0}; show tables like "{1}";'.format(self.database, self.table))
        return self.table in stdout
```

This will produce the desired output.